# Antenna wrap material suitable for lunar & cis-lunar environment

Tags: the-moon, materials, antenna, cislunar

I am looking for a wrap (station) antenna for a transceiver (in space/lunar)

Not all materials are suitable for the space environment.  Does anyone know what wrap antenna materials I can use?

I have found that plastic isn't suitable in space...

**EDIT 1**

It is assumed that the omnidirectional antenna(A wrap or a patch antennas could be used) works in space (lunar) environment. The total dose for my device is 30 – 50 krad. Gain 3-5 dBi. Frequency is S band.

Comment: Hi. What is the purpose of the wrap? Appearance? Thermal protection? Something else? What design criteria does it need to have?

Comment: @JohnHoltz I added info.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient details to respond as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Plastic can be very useful for space, depending on the thermal and cosmic ray deflection properties required.  You might use suitable PCB material such as Kapton FPC which is extremely flexible yet stiff in axial direction.

How would you qualify the acceptance of such materials in specs?
This is your 1st task to define the environmental climate specs with RF (Dk, loss tangent)  and mechanical material properties.

- my 1st BB-VI antenna used tinned braided steel dipole with nylon spool for uncoiling with a 10~20 Hz spin rate. used for VHF.  (circa late 70's)  It was flat rolled for light spring qualities in order to straighten with spin rate.

Comment: I am looking for a COST antenna, it will be the simplest solution.

Comment: @AnnaKoroleva do you mean COTS?